# IMAP server won't response

Tags: c, sockets

I try to create an IMAP client using sockets.
I successfully connect to server and receive welcome message but when trying to login and sending logging information(username and password) server won't response. Here is sample of my code:

```
b_send = send(client_socket, "a1 LOGIN username password", strlen("a1 LOGIN username password"), 0);
if (b_send < 0) 
  perror("ERROR in send");

printf("Sent, waiting for response.\n");

bzero(buf, BUFSIZE);
b_rcv = recv(client_socket, buf, BUFSIZE, 0);
if (b_rcv < 0) 
  perror("ERROR in rcv");

printf("Echo from server: %s", buf);
```

It print out "Sent, waiting for response." and nothing happens. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never sent the required `"\r\n"`.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501 section 2.2.

> All interactions transmitted by client and server are in the form of
> lines, that is, strings that end with a CRLF.

Also, why would you repeat your string like that? Put it in a variable.

Comment: Oh, seems like the solution, let me test it.